# How can I find out all the members who belong to a particular group?

Tags: soql

I am able to list all of their user ids using the following query.

```
 Select g.Group.Name, g.GroupId, g.UserorGroupId 
From GroupMember g WHERE g.group.name = 'Sales'
```

In an attempt to join this with the user object and get the names of the users, I attempted the following query, but it doesn't work. I am missing something, but I am not sure what exactly.

```
Select g.Group.Name, g.GroupId, g.UserorGroupId, 
(select id, name from user__r) From GroupMember g WHERE g.group.name = 'Sales'
```

This throws an error

```
ERROR at Row:1:Column:72
Didn't understand relationship 'user__r' in FROM part of query call.
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Single SOQL query, no Apex required:

```
select id, name, email, isactive, profile.name, userrole.name, usertype
from user 
where id in 
    (select userorgroupid from groupmember where group.name = 'Channel Sales')
```

Comment: Counts as 2 SOQL Statements towards your governor limits though iirc.

Comment: Sure does: "In a SOQL query with parent-child relationship sub-queries, each parent-child relationship counts as an additional query. These types of queries have a limit of three times the number for top-level queries. The row counts from these relationship queries contribute to the row counts of the overall code execution. In addition to static SOQL statements, calls to the following methods count against the number of SOQL statements issued in a request.
*    Database.countQuery
*    Database.getQueryLocator
*    Database.query"

Comment: Hence, "Single SOQL query" seems somewhat misleading.

Comment: Does this handle recursive child groups or groups that contain roles?

Comment: This only queries Users who are direct members of the group `Chanel Sales`.  If another Group is a member of `Chanel Sales`, those Users won't be included in this query (but are considered Group Members in Sharing Rules, Email Alerts, etc.).  You need to perform nested Group Member queries to get all User Members (and this won't include Managers of User Members if the group has `Grant Access Using Hierarchies` as `true`).

Answer (score 4):

Create a Set to Store the UserIds

```
Set<ID> userIDs = New Set<ID>();
User[] usrs = New User[]{};
```

cycle through

```
for(GroupMember g : [Select UserorGroupId From GroupMember WHERE group.name = 'Sales']){
    if(g.UserOrGroupID.getsObjectType() == Schema.User.sObjectType)
         userIDs.add(g.UserOrGroupID);
}

usrs = [Select ID From Users Where ID IN :userIDs];
```

Comment: You got it. I don't think you need to check the Id type though, strictly speaking, as the query simply won't find any matches to a Group Id. It is a good practice though. Alternatively you could add `UserOrGroup.Type = 'User'` to your query.

Comment: @AdrianLarson - All good options. I just typed it up real quick without putting too much thought into it....

Comment: note if a group contains other groups, the problem becomes recursize

Comment: Only if you want the Users in those groups, which is not always the case.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a controller that I have created for this need, it could be a recursive function in order to get the related group types: (E.g. Role, RoleAndSubordinates, etc..) (I got inspired by that [answer](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000009DjGIAU), I hope it could help )

```
public with sharing class GroupMemberController {


    private static Set<Id> getAllSubRoleIds(Set<Id> roleIds) {

        Set<Id> currentRoleIds = new Set<Id>();

        // Get all of the roles underneath the passed roles
        for (UserRole userRole : [
                SELECT Id
                FROM UserRole
                WHERE ParentRoleId IN :roleIds AND ParentRoleId != NULL
        ])
            currentRoleIds.add(userRole.Id);

        // Go fetch some more roles!
        if (currentRoleIds.size() > 0)
            currentRoleIds.addAll(getAllSubRoleIds(currentRoleIds));

        return currentRoleIds;

    }

    public static Set<Id> getUserIdsFromGroups(Set<Id> groupIds) {
        /** Final users result */
        Set<Id> result = new Set<Id>();
        /** Key prefix of SObjects types */
        String userType = Schema.SObjectType.User.getKeyPrefix();
        String groupType = Schema.SObjectType.Group.getKeyPrefix();
        String roleType = Schema.SObjectType.UserRole.getKeyPrefix();
        /** Loop through all group members in a group */
        Set<Id> groupIdProxies = new Set<Id>();
        Set <Id> groupWithRole = new Set<Id>();
        Set<Id> groupWithRoleNSub = new Set<Id>();
        /** get active users and all groups */
        Map<Id, User> activeUsersMap = new Map<Id, User>([SELECT Id FROM User WHERE IsActive = TRUE]);
        Map<Id, Group> groupMap = new Map<Id, Group>([SELECT Id, RelatedId, Type FROM Group]);

        for (Id groupElementId : groupIds) {

            if (String.valueOf(groupElementId.getSobjectType()) == 'Group') {
                for (GroupMember groupMember : [SELECT Id, UserOrGroupId,GroupId,Group.type FROM GroupMember WHERE GroupId IN :groupIds]) {
                    System.debug('Group Member: ' + groupMember);
                    // If the user or group id is a user
                    if (((String) groupMember.UserOrGroupId).startsWith(userType) && activeUsersMap.get(groupMember.UserOrGroupId) != null) {
                        result.add(groupMember.UserOrGroupId);
                    } else if (groupMap.get(groupMember.UserOrGroupId) != null && (groupMap.get(groupMember.UserOrGroupId).RelatedId != null && ((String) groupMap.get(groupMember.UserOrGroupId).RelatedId).startsWith(roleType))) {
                        System.debug('Group Member Type is:::: ' + groupMap.get(groupMember.UserOrGroupId).Type);

                        if (groupMap.get(groupMember.UserOrGroupId).Type == 'Role') {
                            groupWithRole.add(groupMap.get(groupMember.UserOrGroupId).RelatedId);
                        } else if (groupMap.get(groupMember.UserOrGroupId).Type == 'RoleAndSubordinates') {
                            groupWithRoleNSub.add(groupMap.get(groupMember.UserOrGroupId).RelatedId);
                        }
                    }
                    // If the user or group id is a group
                    // Note: there may be a problem with governor limits if this is called too many times
                    else if (((String) groupMember.UserOrGroupId).startsWith(groupType)) {
                        // Call this function again but pass in the group found within this group
                        groupIdProxies.add(groupMember.UserOrGroupId);
                    }
                    else if (groupMap.get(groupMember.UserOrGroupId).Type == 'Organization') {
                        // All active users
                        System.debug('One of group ids in the set contains all internal users');
                        return activeUsersMap.keySet();
                    }
                }
                System.debug('groupWithRole:::: ' + groupWithRole);
                System.debug('groupWithRoleNSub:::: ' + groupWithRoleNSub);
                if (groupWithRoleNSub.size() > 0) {
                    groupWithRoleNSub.addAll(getAllSubRoleIds(groupWithRoleNSub));
                    Map<Id, User> users = new Map<Id, User>([SELECT Id, Name FROM User WHERE UserRoleId IN :groupWithRoleNSub AND isActive = :TRUE]);
                    result.addAll(users.keySet());
                }
                if (groupWithRole.size() > 0) {
                    Map<Id, User> users = new Map<Id, User>([SELECT Id, Name FROM User WHERE UserRoleId IN :groupWithRole AND isActive = :TRUE]);
                    result.addAll(users.keySet());
                }
                // Look for users from other groups
                if (groupIdProxies.size() > 0) {
                    result.addAll(getUserIdsFromGroups(groupIdProxies));
                }
            } else if (String.valueOf(groupElementId.getSobjectType()) == 'CollaborationGroup') {
                for (CollaborationGroupMember collaborationGroupMember : [
                        SELECT Id, CollaborationGroupId,MemberId
                        FROM CollaborationGroupMember
                        WHERE CollaborationGroupId IN :groupIds
                ]) {
                    System.debug('CollaborationGroupMember' + collaborationGroupMember.MemberId);
                    // If the user or group id is a user
                    if (((String) collaborationGroupMember.MemberId).startsWith(userType) && activeUsersMap.get(collaborationGroupMember.MemberId) != null) {
                        result.add(collaborationGroupMember.MemberId);
                    }
                }
            }

        } // END group ids loop
        System.debug('Result Count (Users): ' + result.size());
        System.debug('Result (Users): ' + result);
        return result;
    }


}
```

Comment: There are a lot of queries inside for loop inside this code. This can lead to an exception raised by too many queries.