# How to show a list of QUEUES where a selected User doesn't belong to, excluding QUEUES where other users belong to

Tags: apex, user, queue, lightning-duallistbox

I'm working on a Dual Picklist where in left column I need to show a list of **Queues where a selected user belongs to** and in the  right column a list of **Every Queue that exist on the org besides the Queues that belong to the selected user**.

| Queues from the ORG | Arrows | Queues from User |
| --- | --- | --- |
| All queues from org excluding the Queues from selected User | add> & OR <remove | Queues from selected User |

However I'm struggling to show the Queues from the Org where the User doesn't belong to, with the query: `select id, groupId,group.Name, group.Type from GroupMember where userorGroupId !='00509000007qMJHAA2' and group.type='queue'`I get in return the queues where this person belongs to, but because that Queue belongs to other users too.
To show the Queues where the user belongs to I am using the following queue in Apex class

```
@AuraEnabled (cacheable=true)
public static List<GroupMember>getGroups(string userId, string type){
    List<GroupMember> groupList = new List<GroupMember>();
    if(userId !=''){
        String userIdModal= userId;
        groupList=[select id, groupId,group.Name from GroupMember where userorGroupId !=:userIdModal and group.type=:type];
        
        return groupList;
    }
    return groupList;
}
```

and my JS looks like this

```
@track showModal = false;
@track dataShow;
@api selectedUser;


@wire (getGroups,{userId:'$selectedUser', type:'queue'})
    retrieveGroups ({error, data}) {
       if (data) {
           this.groupList=data;
           
        }else if(error){
            console.log('Sorry,nothing was found');
        }
    }

//use @api because we are accesing info from a parent component
    @api show(){
        this.showModal=true;
    
        console.log(allData);
    }

    handleDialogClose(){
        this.showModal=false
    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can quickly get more difficult depending on your need. The reason is explained well with this question ([Get all queue users](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/301122/get-all-queue-users)), but it comes down to the fact that there's other ways users may be part of a queue without them explicitly being a `GroupMember`:

- User Role
- User Role & Subordinates
- Other Public Groups (ex. All Internal Users)

I'm going to assume you're only leveraging/assigning users directly into queues for your use case. In that case, the problem with your query is that you looking at `GroupMember` which pulls all members across all queues.

You'll want to take a different approach for your SOQL query. What you attempted is just going to give you every `GroupMember` that isn't your user which would be any Group that has "other" members - which could be queues they're apart of or not.

1. Get Queues the User is *not* explicitly assigned to (as a `GroupMember`):

```
SELECT Id,Name 
FROM Group 
WHERE Type = 'Queue' AND ID NOT IN 
(SELECT GroupId FROM GroupMember WHERE UserOrGroupId =: userIdModal)
```

2. Get Queues the User is explicitly assigned to (as a `GroupMember`):

```
SELECT Id,Name 
FROM Group 
WHERE Type = 'Queue' AND ID IN 
(SELECT GroupId FROM GroupMember WHERE UserOrGroupId =: userIdModal)
```

The where criteria in both queries above specifically excludes or includes those groups whose group Id is found in the query against `GroupMember` looking for your specific user.