# How to show a list of ALL USERS NAMES who belong to a selected Group and a list of USERS who don't belong the selected Group

Tags: soql, list, user, queue, public-group

For the moment I have this Query:

```
SELECT userorgroupId, GroupId, Group.Type 
            FROM GroupMember 
            WHERE groupId ='00G09000000vV44EAE'
            AND Group.Type='queue'
```

I am getting the Id's of the users, but I'm not able to get the names.

Comment: How is this any different than your previous question? The `Type` field on Group would allow you to specify which types of groups you're interested in (Queue or Regular Group) - not to mention you could add whatever criteria (Group Name you're looking for, etc) to the query if you have different, specific needs.

Comment: It is different than the previous question, because before I wanted to get a list of Queues where a selectedUser was part of  and now it is the other way around, If I click on a selectedQueue  I need to get a list of USERS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the [previous answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/357830/how-to-show-a-list-of-queues-where-a-selected-user-doesnt-belong-to-excluding) to a similar scenario shows, you can leverage what the documentation goes over under [Semi-Joins with IN and Anti-Joins with NOT IN](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.234.0.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_comparisonoperators.htm)

You care about [User](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.232.0.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_user.htm) and [GroupMember](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_groupmember.htm) in this scenario. As mentioned before and noted in the `GroupMember` docs, you'll be ignoring "other" ways users can be part of a group with this approach.

> User records that are indirect members of Regular public groups are
> not listed as group members. A User can be an indirect member of a
> group if he or she is in a UserRole above the direct group member in
> the hierarchy, or if he or she is a member of a group that is included
> as a subgroup in that group.

As an additional tip, do not hard-code an Id as it can be different per environments if you're deploying new groups. Utilize its developer name at the very least or a custom metadata type if you start having more groups/queues to care about.

For getting *users who are a part of the group*, you'd perform a query on User that returns only users who are also a `GroupMember` in the sub-query against your specific Group Name.

```
SELECT Name 
FROM User 
WHERE isActive = TRUE AND Id IN 
(SELECT UserOrGroupId FROM GroupMember WHERE Group.DeveloperName = 'My Group')
```

For the scenario of *all users that are not in the group*, you can quickly get in trouble if you have many users. You'd want to add some extra criteria to only search for active users and non-community users (and maybe others as well). Depends on your use case, but I wouldn't display a list of all users who are not in the group in a dual listbox if you have 200+ users. You'd want to consider limiting the results and providing some sort of search capability where you'd leverage [LIKE](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_sosl_where.htm) (`LastName LIKE 'john%'`)

```
SELECT Name 
FROM User 
WHERE isActive = TRUE AND UserType = 'Standard' AND Id NOT IN 
(SELECT UserOrGroupId FROM GroupMember WHERE Group.DeveloperName = 'My Group')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't get the user names directly from that query because the GroupMember object is a joining object between User/Group and Group. You need to do another query on the User object to fetch the Name.

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName FROM User WHERE Id IN: userIDsFromGroupMemberQuery
```

Answer (score 0):

select id, name, email, isactive, profile.name,CUID__c,Alias,userrole.name from user where id IN(select UserOrGroupId from GroupMember where group.name = 'your Groupname')