# How to send email to queue through flow

Tags: visual-workflow, email-template

I have created a flow, which is triggering email alert to individual user on certain condition.
But I want to use queue instead of user, anyone could guide me here.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could use a Get Records element to query the Group object. Groups are where queues are defined and that object has a field called Email. You could then use that email address to send the email.

Answer (score 0):

Can you write a little more?
I have Get Records -> Groups and then what?
I don't want to send an email to a "Queue Email" but to all members in the queue.

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE)! This is a Questions & Answers site, not a threaded forum. Please see the various pertinent/relevant notes in [Why and how are some answers deleted?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers), and be aware that your "answer" will likely be deleted. You could ask a [new question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/ask), and in it you can link to this question or its other answer for reference (just click "Share" at the bottom left of the post to get a URL).

Answer (score 0):

There is a more complete answer here: [Get ALL queue Users](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/301122/get-all-queue-users) where the ask was to get all types of queue members, explicitly added users and role/role and subordinate or organization.

Queue members could be one of those groups so it's not as simple enough to say well you can query the email to send to or query the group members. You need to think of all the possible outcomes and then code for that.