# Query Indirect GroupMember Records

Tags: soql, roles, public-group

Is there a way to query GroupMembers who have been granted access indirectly, i.e. via a UserRole?

[image]

The [GroupMember docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_groupmember.htm) imply that no records are created but they are shown in the UI, so I am hoping it possible. For my scenario I really only need to be aware of the Role Id/Group Member. I do not need to traverse up through the role hierarchy.

> A record exists for every User or Group who is a direct member of a
> public group whose Type field is set to Regular. User records that are
> indirect members of Regular public groups are not listed as group
> members. A User can be an indirect member of a group if he or she is
> in a UserRole above the direct group member in the hierarchy, or if he
> or she is a member of a group that is included as a subgroup in that
> group.

[image]

Comment: this [question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/301122/get-all-queue-users/301142#301142) may be of interest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My experimentation seems to indicate that for a `UserRole` you add to a `Group`, Salesforce adds a `Group` with `Type = 'Role'` and `RelatedId = <UserRole.Id>`. You may need to separately process `RoleAndSubordinates` and/or `RoleAndSubordinatesInternal`, depending on your requirements.

Regardless, you should be able to query for the Id of the `UserRole` by iterating through the `GroupMember` records and filtering by `Type`. As there are many `Type` values to inspect, if you want to properly handle all of them you may need to do more legwork, as you shouldn't trust my back-of-the-napkin implementation. But it should get you started, hopefully.

```
Set<Id> roles = new Set<Id>();
Set<Id> rolesWithSubordinate = new Set<Id>();

Set<Id> groupIds = new Set<Id>();
for (GroupMember member : myGroup)
    groupIds.add(member.UserOrGroupId);

for (Group record : [
    SELECT Type, RelatedId FROM Group WHERE Id IN :groupIds
]){
    switch on record.Type
    {
        when 'Role'
        {
            roles.add(record.RelatedId);
        }
        when 'RoleAndSubordinates'
        {
            rolesWithSubordinate.add(record.RelatedId);
        }
    }
}
// query users with the above roles here
```

Comment: Thanks, it was knowledge of the sneaky Role Groups that got me there.

Comment: Yeah I didn't know off the top of my head either.